# find minimum values in CGFloat obtained in a loop

Tags: objective-c, minimum, cgfloat, cgrectmake

I am drawing reactangles in a loop based on the parameters that I get from the looping variable event as below :

```
CGRectMake(cellWidth * event.xOffset,(cellHeight / MINUTES_IN_TWO_HOURS * [event minutesSinceEvent]), cellWidth,cellHeight / MINUTES_IN_TWO_HOURS * [event durationInMinutes]);
```

in every loop the `minutesSinceEvent` and `durationInMinutes` changes, so a different reactangle gets drawn every time.

I want to get the lowest y value in the loop and the greatest height in the loop. Simply saying, I want to have the y value of the rectangle which is above all. And the height of the rectangle which extends below all.

Please let me know, if any other information is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be to accumulate all rectangles in a union rectangle:

```
CGRect unionRect = CGRectNull;
for (...) {
    CGRect currentRect = ...;
    unionRect = CGRectUnion(unionRect, currentRect);
}
NSLog(@"min Y : %f", CGRectGetMinY(unionRect));
NSLog(@"height: %f", CGRectGetHeight(unionRect));
```

What this does is basically to calculate a rectangle that is large enough to contain all rectangles that were created in the loop (but no larger).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare another `CGRect` variable before the loop and track the value inside:

```
CGRect maxRect = CGRectZero;
maxRect.origin.y = HUGE_VALF; //this is to set a very big number of y so the first one you compare to will be always lower - you can set a different number of course...
for(......)
{
    CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(cellWidth * event.xOffset,(cellHeight / MINUTES_IN_TWO_HOURS * [event minutesSinceEvent]), cellWidth,cellHeight / MINUTES_IN_TWO_HOURS * [event durationInMinutes]);

   if(currentRect.origin.y < maxRect.origin.y)
       maxRect.origin.y = currentRect.origin.y;

   if(currentRect.size.height > maxRect.size.height)
       maxRect.size.height = currentRect.size.height;
}

//After the loop your maxRect.origin.y will be the lowest and your maxRect.size.height will be the greatest...
```